# COMO CREAR DOS WEBVIEWS CON COOKIES DIFERENTES

Tags: java, android

`CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(true);`

//este es mi código para activar las cookies el problema es que quiero INICIAR sesiones diferentes en dos webview diferentes y si inicio sesión en un webview en el otro webview también se inicia al abrirlo **ósea quiero que cada webview tenga su propia cookie.**

Comment: Está [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26323050/how-to-achieve-multi-login-for-webviews-in-android/26525546#26525546) , ¿Te sirve?

Comment: CAda WebView se mostrarìa en diferente Activity?